# faillock marks correct password as wrong on RHEL6

Tags: linux, shadow, rhel, rhel6, passwd

I've been having a mysterious problem of being unable to login to my root account via SSH or Console. This is a real physical machine, not a VM. Luckily I still have a sudo user to experiment with.

**RHEL6**

- `$ su root` from another user works fine, so the password is correct
- Login via Putty SSH **does not work**. Returns `Access denied`
- Login directly via keyboard also **does not work**. Returns `Incorrect login`

---

My pam.d settings are set to lock accounts and I can see the locked accounts with

- `$ sudo failock --root`.

If enter the wrong password wrong 3 times, my root will be blocked due to *pam* settings, and at that point, `$ su root` will also stop working. So I reset my blocked accounts with:

- `$ sudo faillock --user root reset`

---

Looking at `$ sudo failock --root`, I can see the *denied access* being logged as I am doing them. 
Trying to connect via SSH or keyboard directly with ***correct password*** also  ***makes a log entry***

**Anyway - my root account is locked somewhere and I don't know how to unlock it**

---

---

Some other settings:

```
    $ sudo chage -l root 
    Last password change                                    : Feb 14, 2020
    Password expires                                        : never
    Password inactive                                       : never
    Account expires                                         : never
    Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
    Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
    Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

```
    # /etc/passwd
    root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

```
    # /etc/shadow
    root:$6$SALTSALT$HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_HASH_H:18306:0:99999:7:::
```

```
    # /etc/pam.d/system-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so  try_first_pass
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok remember=5
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

```
    # /etc/pam.d/password-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail even_deny_root deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by 2 separate problems:

**1**

File `/etc/securetty` file was empty, so I added: `tty1` to it.

### [unitstackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41840/effect-of-entries-in-etc-securetty)

**2**

File `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` had `PermitRootLogin` uncommented, so I commented it and restartred sshd service.

---

I still do have a problem, since there is a service that is creating an empty `/etc/securetty` file if it does not exist, but I will try to track this down eventually.